# H2 database: Is NIO JVM bug message related to H2 (and possibly database corruption)?

Tags: h2, nio, corruption, embedded-database

We're currently using H2 version 199 in embedded mode with default nio file protocol and MVStore storage system. In some installations we encounter DB corruption within minutes after batch operations (a mix of about 30.000 deletes, inserts and updates).

Within 45 seconds of the last insert and roughly 90 seconds before the app detects that the DB is corrupt , we see the following two lines in the log file:

```
org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@3180ea95 JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay 3 times
org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@3180ea95 JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 3 times, canceled keys 51 times
```

Is H2 responsible for these log messages? Are they related to the database corruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, H2 is not responsible for those messages.
Who is? My 30 sec. Google search shows Jetty as a possible culprit.

Comment: Thank you @andrei. It was just the combination of an NIO log message and the H2 NIO protocol as opposed to the async protocol that made me wonder.